# Efficiently calculate optical flow parameters - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vectorization

I am implementing the partial derivative equations from the [Horn & Schunck paper](http://image.diku.dk/imagecanon/material/HornSchunckOptical_Flow.pdf) on optical flow. However, even for relative small images (320x568), it takes a frustratingly long time (~30-40 seconds) to complete. I assume this is due to the 320 x 568 = 181760 loop iterations, but I can't figure out a more efficient way to do this (short of a MEX file).

Is there some way to turn this into a more efficient MATLAB operation (a convolution perhaps)? I can figure out how to do this as a convolution for `It` but not `Ix` and `Iy`. I've also considered matrix shifting, but that only works for `It` as well, as far as I can figure out.

Has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution?

My code is below:

```
function [Ix, Iy, It] = getFlowParams(img1, img2)

% Make sure image dimensions match up
assert(size(img1, 1) == size(img2, 1) && size(img1, 2) == size(img2, 2), ...
    'Images must be the same size');
assert(size(img1, 3) == 1, 'Images must be grayscale');

% Dimensions of original image
[rows, cols] = size(img1);
Ix = zeros(numel(img1), 1);
Iy = zeros(numel(img1), 1);
It = zeros(numel(img1), 1);

% Pad images to handle edge cases
img1 = padarray(img1, [1,1], 'post');
img2 = padarray(img2, [1,1], 'post');

% Concatenate i-th image with i-th + 1 image
imgs = cat(3, img1, img2);

% Calculate energy for each pixel
for i = 1 : rows
    for j = 1 : cols
        cube = imgs(i:i+1, j:j+1, :);
        Ix(sub2ind([rows, cols], i, j)) = mean(mean(cube(:, 2, :) - cube(:, 1, :)));
        Iy(sub2ind([rows, cols], i, j)) = mean(mean(cube(2, :, :) - cube(1, :, :)));
        It(sub2ind([rows, cols], i, j)) = mean(mean(cube(:, :, 2) - cube(:, :, 1)));
    end
end
```

Comment: There are several optical flow algorithms implemented in the Computer Vision System Toolbox. See `opticalFlowHS`, `opticalFlowLK`, `opticalFlowFarneback`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`2D convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) is the way to go here as also predicted in the question to replace those heavy `mean/average` calculations. Also, those iterative differentiations could be replaced by [MATLAB's `diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html). Thus, incorporating all that, a vectorized implementation would be -

```
%// Pad images to handle edge cases
img1 = padarray(img1, [1,1], 'post');
img2 = padarray(img2, [1,1], 'post');

%// Store size parameters for later usage
[m,n] = size(img1);

%// Differentiation along dim-2 on input imgs for Ix calculations
df1 = diff(img1,[],2)
df2 = diff(img2,[],2)

%// 2D Convolution to simulate average calculations & reshape to col vector
Ixvals = (conv2(df1,ones(2,1),'same') + conv2(df2,ones(2,1),'same'))./4;
Ixout = reshape(Ixvals(1:m-1,:),[],1);

%// Differentiation along dim-1 on input imgs for Iy calculations
df1 = diff(img1,[],1)
df2 = diff(img2,[],1)

%// 2D Convolution to simulate average calculations & reshape to col vector
Iyvals = (conv2(df1,ones(1,2),'same') + conv2(df2,ones(1,2),'same'))./4
Iyout = reshape(Iyvals(:,1:n-1),[],1);

%// It just needs elementwise diffentiation between input imgs.
%// 2D convolution to simulate mean calculations & reshape to col vector
Itvals = conv2(img2-img1,ones(2,2),'same')./4
Itout = reshape(Itvals(1:m-1,1:n-1),[],1)
```

Benefits with such a vectorized implementation would be :

- Memory efficiency : No more concatenation along the third dimension that would incur memory overhead. Again, performance wise it would be a benefit as we won't need to index into such *heavy arrays*.
- The iterative differentiations inside the loopy codes are replaced by differentiation with [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), so this should be another improvement.
- Those expensive average calculations are replaced by very fast convolution calculations and this should be the major improvement section.

Comment: @marcman The `img1` and `img2` I was using were the padded versions from your code. So, that should take care of the edges and precisely that's why I need that slicing and reshaping at the end. Check out the edited code on all these and some comments at the end.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @marcman Ah also if you don't mind, would like to know the runtimes with the vectorized approach on your actual input case and some comparison with the original loopy one :)

Comment: @marcman Nice!! Not too bad as compared to original 30-40 secs! :)

Comment: @marcman Thanks for the edit suggestions, but I did check my version against your original one before posting this solution. So, I would think the solution won't need that swapping as you suggested in the edit.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks Ray! Means alot coming from an Image Proc. guru! :)

Answer (score 2):

A faster method, with improved results (in the cases I have observed) is the following:

```
function [Ix, Iy, It] = getFlowParams(imNew,imPrev)

gg = [0.2163, 0.5674, 0.2163]; 
f = imNew + imPrev; 
Ix = f(:,[2:end end]) - f(:,[1 1:(end-1)]); 
Ix = conv2(Ix,gg','same');

Iy = f([2:end end],:) - f([1 1:(end-1)],:); 
Iy = conv2(Iy,gg ,'same');

It = 2*conv2(gg,gg,imNew - imPrev,'same');
```

This handles the boundary cases elegantly.

I made this as part of my [optical flow toolbox](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44400-tutorial-and-toolbox-on-real-time-optical-flow), where you can easily view H&S, Lucas Kanade and more in realtime. In the toolbox, the function is called grad3D.m. You may also want to check out grad3Drec.m, in the same toolbox, which adds simple temporal blurring.

Comment: I think I should add at least 2 notes to this algorithm: 1) It can be easily adapted for integer operations by simply changing the gg filter to [1,2,1];       2) The boundary elements will be weighted slightly less then they should (considering they are single sided differences). This is actually desired for optical flow applications, but IT MAY ADVERSLY AFFECT OTHER APPS, such as more general numerical solvers. So BEWARE